# How to save connection in Jconsole tool

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I have written a Java service to run on a server.

I used `JMX` and `jconsole` to monitor the service from myPC.

In order to connect, I have to copy and paste the following link into `jconsole`:

```
service:jmx:rmi://192.168.5.207:9999/jndi/rmi://192.168.5.207:9999/jmxrmi
```

After quitting `jconsole`, If I want to reconnect, I have to copy and paste the link again.

Is there a way to save the link in `jconsole` so that I can reuse it?

Or can you suggest another remote monitor tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, you will not be able to save URLs in JConsole. You can use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) instead. It is very good tool which has all the functionality as JConsole with some very good extra features.

Comment: Thanks nIKUNJ. VisualVM is which I'm finding. It very good for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the URL as program argument:

> **jconsole [ options ] [ pid | [ host:port ]]**
>
> **pid**
>
> Process ID of a local Java VM that was started with the system property com.sun.management.jmxremote. The Java VM must be running with the same user ID as the user ID running jconsole. See JMX Monitoring and Management for details.
>
> **host:port**
>
> Name of the host system on which the Java VM is running and the port number specified by the system property com.sun.management.jmxremote.port when the JVM was started. See JMX Monitoring and Management for details.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jconsole.html